# How to get the physical (absolute) page number

Tags: page-numbering

I have an article of nine pages which include three kinds of page number styles – `Roman`, `arabic` and `Alph`. The layout of the pages and their logical numbers are: `I II 1 2 3 4 A B C`.

I want to get the physical (absolute) page number of a given page from a macro (or counter). For example, it should be `7` for the page with logical number `A`, and `5` for the page with logical number `3`.

I tried with the LaTeX macro `\ReadonlyShipoutCounter`, but this macro did not give the right number.

Anyone can help me? Preferably without using other packages.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,fancyhdr}
\geometry{showframe}
\pagestyle{fancy}

% My Try: (not succeessful)
\newcommand\abspagenumber{\the\ReadonlyShipoutCounter}

% My Intent:
\newcommand\abspage{...}%output the absolute page number of a certain page in article

\rhead{\thepage}
\chead{Currrent Physical Page Number is: \abspagenumber}
%\lhead{Currrent Physical Page Number is: \abspage}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
first page\par current absolute page number is: \abspagenumber
% The absolute page number of this page is: \abspage.
\clearpage
sencond page\par current absolute page number is: \abspagenumber
% The absolute page number of this page is: \abspage.
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
third page\par current absolute page number is: \abspagenumber
% The absolute page number of this page is: \abspage.
\clearpage
fourth page\par current absolute page number is: \abspagenumber
% The absolute page number of this page is: \abspage.
\clearpage
fifth page\par current absolute page number is: \abspagenumber
% The absolute page number of this page is: \abspage.
\clearpage
sixth page\par current absolute page number is: \abspagenumber
% The absolute page number of this page is: \abspage.
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{Alph}
seventh page\par current absolute page number is: \abspagenumber
% The absolute page number of this page is: \abspage.
\clearpage
eighth page\par current absolute page number is: \abspagenumber\par
% The absolute page number of this page is: \abspage.
\clearpage
nineth page\par current absolute page number is: \abspagenumber
% The absolute page number of this page is: \abspage.
\end{document}
```

---

#### Edit:

Base on the solution given by Ulrike Fischer I have another request:
How can I make `\abspagenumber` work in a watermark?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,fancyhdr,eso-pic}
\geometry{showframe}
\pagestyle{fancy}


\newcommand\abspagenumber{\inteval{\ReadonlyShipoutCounter+1}}

\rhead{\thepage}
\chead{Currrent Physical Page Number is: \abspagenumber}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
first page\par current absolute page number is: \abspagenumber
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\AtPageCenter{\abspagenumber}}

\clearpage
sencond page\par current absolute page number is: \abspagenumber

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
third page\par current absolute page number is: \abspagenumber

\clearpage
fourth page\par current absolute page number is: \abspagenumber

\clearpage
fifth page\par current absolute page number is: \abspagenumber
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\AtPageCenter{\abspagenumber}}
\clearpage
sixth page\par current absolute page number is: \abspagenumber
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you load the hyperref packge, you can use the count `\Hy@pagecounter` (all counters are  counts, but not all counts are counters).

Comment: @John Kormylo I tried `\the\Hy@pagecounter` in each page of my article, and they all typeset 0. As I don't fine related description about the count `\Hy@pagecounter` in the manuel, would you provide with an example or answer to illustrate how to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the new hook facility provided by the LaTeX kernel to calculate the current abs. page number and to add the watermark:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry,fancyhdr}
\geometry{showframe}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\AtBeginDocument{\xdef\currentPageNumber{1}}
\AddToHook{shipout/after}{\xdef\currentPageNumber{\inteval{\ReadonlyShipoutCounter+1}}}

\rhead{\thepage}
\chead{Current Physical Page Number is: \currentPageNumber}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
first page\par current absolute page number is: \currentPageNumber
\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{% upper left page corner coordinate is (0,0)
  \unitlength=\paperheight
  \put(0,-0.5){\makebox[\paperwidth][c]{\currentPageNumber}}
}

\clearpage
sencond page\par current absolute page number is: \currentPageNumber

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
third page\par current absolute page number is: \currentPageNumber

\clearpage
fourth page\par current absolute page number is: \currentPageNumber

\clearpage
fifth page\par current absolute page number is: \currentPageNumber
\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{
  \unitlength=\paperheight
  \put(0,-0.5){\makebox[\paperwidth][c]{\currentPageNumber}}
}
\clearpage
sixth page\par current absolute page number is: \currentPageNumber
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

You only need to add one to the counter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,fancyhdr}
\geometry{showframe}
\pagestyle{fancy}


\newcommand\abspagenumber{\inteval{\ReadonlyShipoutCounter+1}}

\rhead{\thepage}
\chead{Currrent Physical Page Number is: \abspagenumber}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
first page\par current absolute page number is: \abspagenumber

\clearpage
sencond page\par current absolute page number is: \abspagenumber

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
third page\par current absolute page number is: \abspagenumber

\clearpage
fourth page\par current absolute page number is: \abspagenumber

\clearpage
fifth page\par current absolute page number is: \abspagenumber

\clearpage
sixth page\par current absolute page number is: \abspagenumber

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{Alph}
seventh page\par current absolute page number is: \abspagenumber
\clearpage
eighth page\par current absolute page number is: \abspagenumber\par

\clearpage
nineth page\par current absolute page number is: \abspagenumber
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a similar command readily available for the total page count (last page shipout #) of a document?

Comment: @AlexG \PreviousTotalPages, see ltshipout-doc.pdf

Comment: Nice, no more `zref` woes!

Comment: @AlexG the shipout/lastpage hook needs to know the last page too ;-)

Comment: Yes, of course, but I wasn't aware of these user-interface commands.

Comment: @AlexG we don't reserve the good stuff only for us ;-)

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer In my system, `\inteval` leads to `ERROR: Undefined control sequence.`. Do I miss something?

Comment: your system is too old. Load the xfp package.

Comment: Which part should be updated to make \inteval work without explicitly calling xfp package?

Comment: you need to update LaTeX.

Comment: @lyl Update your TeX distribution, current is TeXLive-2022.

Comment: @lyl You may do `\newcommand{\abspagenumber}{\the\numexpr\ReadonlyShipoutCounter+1\relax}`, but updating your TeX system is ***much*** better.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer @egreg This solution works very well wthen `\abspagenumber` is used in the body of document. But when using it in watermark like `\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\AtPageCenter{\abspagenumber}}`, it gives uncorrect number. So, is there a better way to make `\abspagenumber` workable for both? It will be boring to remember +1 or not.

Comment: *Within* the shipout routine, you may not need to add 1 to get the current page number. Just use `\ReadonlyShipoutCounter`.

Comment: Thank you @ AlexG. I had been believed that  the problem may be related to shipout/before/after, and this field is hard to me. In this post, is it possible to determine the condtion whether it's in body or in background in the defination of the macro `\abspagenumber` ?

Comment: Within the shipout routine you could define a local macro such as `\def\insideshipout{}` whose existence you then test within your `\abspagenumber` command: `\ifdefined\insideshipout ... \else ...\fi`.

Comment: @lyl I must correct myself. Since `\ReadonlyShipoutCounter` is incremented only *after* the page has been shipped out, its value should be the same in both the page body *and* during shipout, hence starting with zero for both.

Answer (score 4):

Still there, but no longer default.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,fancyhdr}
\geometry{showframe}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\Hy@pagecounter=1
\newcommand\abspagenumber{\the\Hy@pagecounter}
\makeatother

\rhead{\thepage}
\chead{Currrent Physical Page Number is: \abspagenumber}
%\lhead{Currrent Physical Page Number is: \abspage}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
first page\par current absolute page number is: \abspagenumber
% The absolute page number of this page is: \abspage.
\clearpage
sencond page\par current absolute page number is: \abspagenumber
% The absolute page number of this page is: \abspage.
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
third page\par current absolute page number is: \abspagenumber
% The absolute page number of this page is: \abspage.
\clearpage
fourth page\par current absolute page number is: \abspagenumber
% The absolute page number of this page is: \abspage.
\clearpage
fifth page\par current absolute page number is: \abspagenumber
% The absolute page number of this page is: \abspage.
\clearpage
sixth page\par current absolute page number is: \abspagenumber
% The absolute page number of this page is: \abspage.
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{Alph}
seventh page\par current absolute page number is: \abspagenumber
% The absolute page number of this page is: \abspage.
\clearpage
eighth page\par current absolute page number is: \abspagenumber\par
% The absolute page number of this page is: \abspage.
\clearpage
nineth page\par current absolute page number is: \abspagenumber
% The absolute page number of this page is: \abspage.
\end{document}
```