# Document with Same Page Numbers and Page Anchoring

Tags: hyperref, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I want to have a document that resets the page number at 1 at some point. For example: Page 1 of 2, Page 2 of 2, Page 1 of 3, Page 2 of 3, Page 3 of 3, Page 1 of 1, Page 1 of 5, Page 2 of 5, and so on.

This can be done by using \pagenumbering{arabic} or \setcounter{page}{1} when I want to restart the page number somewhere. The problem is that I want to make page anchors using hyperref but clicking the page number directs me to a wrong page and not the desired page destination.

Below is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[pageanchor, pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage[headheight=5pt, hmargin=1in, vmargin=0.5in]{geometry}


\NewDocumentCommand\pagetargetref{m}{%
    \hyperlink{page.\getpagerefnumber{#1}}{\pageref*{#1}}}


\fancypagestyle{fancy1}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{Upper Left Header  \\
        Lower Left Header}
    \fancyhead[R]{Upper Right Header  \\
        Lower Right Header}
    \fancyfoot[L]{}
    \fancyfoot[R]{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{Page \thepage\ of \pagetargetref{page:2}} 
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
}



\fancypagestyle{fancy2}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{Header 1  \\  Header 2}
    \fancyhead[R]{Header 3 \\  Header 4}
    \fancyfoot[L]{}
    \fancyfoot[R]{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{Page \thepage\ of \pagetargetref{page:2}} 
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
}


\fancypagestyle{fancy3}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{Header A  \\   Header B}
    \fancyhead[R]{Header C  \\  Header D}
    \fancyfoot[L]{}
    \fancyfoot[R]{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{Page \thepage\ of \pagetargetref{page:3new}} 
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
}


\fancypagestyle{fancy4}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{Header Here  \\ Header There}
    \fancyhead[R]{Header Here \\  Header There}
    \fancyfoot[L]{}
    \fancyfoot[R]{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{Page \thepage\ of \pagetargetref{page:3new}} 
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
}



\fancypagestyle{fancy5}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{Header Here  \\ Header There}
    \fancyhead[R]{Header Here \\  Header There}
    \fancyfoot[L]{}
    \fancyfoot[R]{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{Page \thepage\ of \pagetargetref{page:5another}} 
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
}




\fancypagestyle{fancy6}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{Header Here  \\ Header There}
    \fancyhead[R]{Header Here \\  Header There}
    \fancyfoot[L]{}
    \fancyfoot[R]{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{Page \thepage\ of \pagetargetref{page:5another}} 
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
}



\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{fancy1}
\pagestyle{fancy2}

\label{page:1}

This is Page 1.

\newpage

\label{page:2}

This is Page 2.


\clearpage

\setcounter{page}{1}

\newpage

\thispagestyle{fancy3}
\pagestyle{fancy4}

\label{page:1new}

This is New Page 1.

\newpage

\label{page:2new}

This is New Page 2.

 \newpage
 
 \label{page:3new}
 
 This is New Page 3.
 
 
 \clearpage
 
 \setcounter{page}{1}
 
 \newpage
 
 \thispagestyle{fancy5}
 \pagestyle{fancy6}
 
 \label{page:1another}
 
 This is another page 1. 
 
 \newpage
 
 \label{page:2another}
 
 This is another page 2.
 
 \newpage
 
 \label{page:3another}
 
 This is another page 3.
 
 \newpage
 
 \label{page:4another}
 
 This is another page 4.
 
 \newpage
 
 \label{page:5another}
 
 This is another page 5.


\end{document}
```

In this MWE, first two pages are page-referenced to the second page, the next three pages are page-referenced to the third page in this set, and the last five pages are page-referenced to the last page in this set.

The page links are not working properly and they direct me to another pages. Is there a way to fix this? I know I can use other page numbering styles but I want to stick to arabic only. In case it helps, I use XeLaTeX in compiling my documents as I use PSTricks in my documents.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: (i) `paperwidth=8.27in, paperheight=11.69in` is redundant since you've set the document class option `a4paper`. (ii) `left=1.00in, right=1.00in, top=0.50in, bottom=0.50in` may be expressed more succinctly as `hmargin=1in, vmargin=0.5in`.

Comment: @Mico Indeed, the OP is ensuring inconsistent results with excessive verbosity. As you point out, equally poor results can be obtained with less typing. OP: you ignore `fancyhdr`'s warnings at your peril. The package is altering your settings when it realises, but, by then, it is too late to ensure consistent results.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/659781/how-to-get-the-physical-absolute-page-number

Comment: @JohnKormylo the link only instructs on how to get the actual (absolute) page number of a page.

Comment: sorry why do you number the pages like this? As a reader I would simply go mad if I have to wonder if a "see page 3" means the first page 3 or the third. And no, the fact that there is an internal link does not help if a page is referenced from the outside, e.g. in speech or in some other document.