# Get the real/actual page number despite the numbering

Tags: page-numbering

Having a document with different page numberings: roman (i,ii,etc.) and arabic (1,2,etc.) and the chapters setting the `\setcounter{page}{1}`.

How to get the "real/actual" page number despite the numbering?

In the following example we have two roman-numerated pages, and two chapters of 2 pages each. This are 6 "real/actual" pages.

```
i  -> 1
ii -> 2
1  -> 3
2  -> 4
1  -> 5
2  -> 6
```

**Update**
MWE as requested:

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\let\oldchapter\chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}[1]{
    \oldchapter{#1}
    \par\noindent Page:~ \thepage
    \par\noindent Absolute:~ ??? % <- here I need the real/actual page
}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\chapter{Primus}
\par\lipsum
\chapter{Secundus}
\par\lipsum
\mainmatter
\chapter{First}
\par\lipsum
\chapter{Second}
\par\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: depends where you want to use the absolute page number so provide a complete example.

Comment: In OpTeX, there is the counter `\gpageno` which counts the absolute page number.

Comment: @wipet we have a counter too, but due to the asynchronous page breaking you still need to decide if you can use it directly (in the header) or if you need to go through an auxiliary file and a reference (in the text body).

Comment: Is this just academic curiosity or you have an application in mind?

Comment: side remark: hyperref won't like if if there are more than one page 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/659781/how-to-get-the-physical-absolute-page-number

Comment: @egreg I need to extract (absolute) pages from the generated pdfs with `qpdf`.

Comment: If you use the `memoir` class instead, then it has some extra counters that goes along with the page number, but count absolute, `sheetsequence`. There are also values for the last sheet and last page.

Comment: and where do you want to see it?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Where the question marks (???) are placed.

Comment: @wolfrevo And what has this to do with TeX? With `qpdf in.pdf --pages in.pdf 2-3 -- out.pdf` I get `out.pdf` with the absolute pages 2 and 3 from `in.pdf`

Comment: @egreg And how do I get `2` and `3`? `\thepage` gives me `ii` and `1`. That's why I need the absolute page.

Comment: @egreg BTW: AFAIK `qpdf` works only with absolute pages. See my question on SO https://stackoverflow.com/q/77402801/1659599

Comment: @wolfrevo That's just doing a subtraction…

Comment: @egreg That's right. Provided you know how many roman-numbered pages are in the document.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that page counters (both \thepage and totalpages) are not always reliable in the text body due to the asynchronous page breaking. Directly behind \chapter it should work.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\let\oldchapter\chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}[1]{
    \oldchapter{#1}
    \par\noindent Page:~ \thepage
    \par\noindent Absolute:~ \inteval{\value{totalpages}+1} % <- here I need the real/actual page
}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\chapter{Primus}
\par\lipsum
\chapter{Secundus}
\par\lipsum
\mainmatter
\chapter{First}
\par\lipsum
\chapter{Second}
\par\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

In OpTeX, we can use `\gpageno`. Be aware that page counters (both `\pageno` and `\gpageno`) are not always reliable in the text body due to the asynchronous page breaking. Directly behind `\chap` it should work.

```
\def\lipsum{\lorem[1-12]}
\let\printchap_ori=\_printchap
\def\_printchap#1{%
   \printchap_ori{#1}
   \par\noindent Page:~\folio
   \par\noindent Absolute:~\the\numexpr\gpageno+1\relax
   \par
}

\pageno=-1
\nonum\chap Primus
\lipsum
\nonum\chap Secundus
\lipsum
\vfil\break \pageno=1
\chap First
\lipsum
\chap Second
\lipsum

\bye
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to add hooks to `\mainmatter` and to `\chapter` to write annotations in an auxiliary file.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry} % just to get smaller pictures
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newwrite\qpdfcommands
\immediate\openout\qpdfcommands=\jobname-qpdf.commands

\newcommand{\getlastpagenumber}{%
  \inteval{\value{page}\ifodd\value{page}+1\fi}%
}

\AddToHook{cmd/mainmatter/before}{%
  \xdef\pagesinthefrontmatter{\getlastpagenumber}
}
\AddToHook{cmd/chapter/before}{%
  \ifnum\value{chapter}>0
    \immediate\write\qpdfcommands{%
      qpdf --empty --pages \jobname.pdf
      \inteval{\firstpageofprevious+\pagesinthefrontmatter}-%
      \inteval{\getlastpagenumber+\pagesinthefrontmatter}
      -- \jobname-\arabic{chapter}.pdf%
    }%
    \xdef\firstpageofprevious{\inteval{\getlastpagenumber+1}}%
  \else
    \gdef\firstpageofprevious{1}%
  \fi
}
\AtEndDocument{%
  \immediate\write\qpdfcommands{%
    qpdf --empty --pages \jobname.pdf
    \inteval{\firstpageofprevious+\pagesinthefrontmatter}-z
    -- \jobname-\arabic{chapter}.pdf%
  }%
  \immediate\closeout\qpdfcommands
}

\begin{document}

\huge

\frontmatter

This is page \thepage

\clearpage

This is page \thepage

\clearpage

This is page \thepage

\mainmatter

\chapter{First}

\lipsum[1-10]

\chapter{Second}

\lipsum[11-30]

\chapter{Third}

\lipsum[31-60]

\end{document}
```

Try it and you see that the written file will contain

```
qpdf --empty --pages qpex.pdf 5-28 -- qpex-1.pdf
qpdf --empty --pages qpex.pdf 29-70 -- qpex-2.pdf
qpdf --empty --pages qpex.pdf 71-z -- qpex-3.pdf
```

I leave as an exercise how to cope with `\backmatter`.

Comment: Your example is interesting. But not exactly what I am searching for. Think of it as the following task: Extract the single chapters/sections from the whole pdf. I've done this with different approaches. One of them marks the start and end of the chapter and writes a qpdf command with the pages to a file. But this works only if there is only one page counter/numbering. As soon as there are more numberings (either in frontmatter with roman-numbering or by setting the page nr in some parts) I need the absolute pages.

Comment: @wolfrevo Look at the present version

Comment: FYI: Workaround to use "relative" pages in a pagelabel with qpdf: https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf/issues/1060#issuecomment-1793765046